# Is there one complete list showing Traditional characters in Simplified?

Tags: resources, traditional-vs-simplified

*Or are there really that many that I'm asking a dumb question?*

I've started learning traditional characters first and once I gather the knowledge of around 2000-3000 characters I was thinking of learning the simplified versions of the words I know, and in order to make an Anki list I was wondering if there's one comprehensive list with all the different words/characters.

謝謝!

Comment: Be aware that in some cases there is not a one to one mapping of simplified <-> traditional (which somewhat complicates entering them in Anki). You can find a comprehensive list of such cases [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambiguities_in_Chinese_character_simplification).

Comment: There isn't deterministic relationship between these two scripts, different writing system may use different characters for the same word, different dialect may use different words to express the same meaning. Look for the newest official document published by the local government, you can find an answer which is ONLY useful when talking about local official standard language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's one [here](http://www.sayjack.com/chinese/simplified-to-traditional-chinese-conversion-table/) with 2580 characters.

Answer (score 1):

For your purpose, instead of learning from a huge list of word pairs, you can use [OpenCC](http://opencc.byvoid.com/). It allows you to convert between simplified and traditional Chinese. One big advantage of learning with this tool is that you can also learn different word-choices among the Chinese-speaking communities, e.g. Taiwan, Hong Kong, Mainland China.

Answer (score 0):

Also though there are a couple hundred exceptions you might need where entire arrangements of radicals are changed, for the most part you just need to learn the minority of radicals that change between the two. Most of the characters you will come across are the same - 9; those that aren't, most change a radical in a standard way. I learn the two concurrently, 85 adds much less than learning the characters themselves.